# PrimeNG editor: & parsing issue

Tags: angular, editor, primeng

I am using PrimeNG p-editor in my Angular project. When I type & in the editor, it does not parse it correctly and parses it as &

Even the documentation page of PrimeNG editor has the same behavior.
Any idea on how to fix it or any workaround ?

PrimeNG version being used in my project is 7.

Code:
HTML:

`<p-editor [(ngModel)]="text1" [style]="{'height':'200px'}"></p-editor>`

TS:
`text1: string = '';`

If I type "Tom & Jerry" in the editor, the "&" is interpreted as ampersand.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hello, well angular is handling the content and strips the special characters tthat could seem unsafe. Still, ampersand character will be displayed as `&` character when you will show the content in another component. But in order to display the stored / transcripted content you need another pEditor in readonly mode, or maybe some kind of DIV with `innerHTML` content.

Comment: That's what I was also thinking, to show my content in innerHTML attribute. However, I have this editor at a lot of places in my application. Maybe I can try attaching a blur event and then replace /&amp;/ with & on blur.

Comment: I wouldn't do like that, but you could try of course. I use pEditor in readonly mode and it has a huge advantage, it renders exactly like the edit mode, so no trouble having to handle any special character :) Cheers.